# Why does cutting onions cause tears?​

Tags: biochemistry, botany

Why does cutting onions cause tears?​ From a couple of sites, I found that it is because of sulfuric acid produced by onions. But I could not find more details. What is the biochemical pathway by which onions cause tears? Also, which compound is responsible for it? If it is enzyme-catalyzed reaction, can we just stop the production of this enzyme without causing any side-effects?

Comment: Your last sentence refers to the Vidalia Onion, IIRC.  Lacking sufficient sulpher, it doesn’t produce significant quantities of the irritating sulfoxide.

Comment: Related advice: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/567/28937

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Interesting question! The cause of tears and itching is the chemicals produced by onion (*Allium cepa*). Lets go into some details.

Onions, coming from the family Liliaceae (also containing garlic, chives, scallions and leeks) store compounds known as amino acid sulfoxides, and the one we are talking about here is S-1-propenyl-L-cysteine sulfoxide (abbreviated as PRENCSO), also calles isoalliin (due to its similarity with alliin found in garlic). When onion is damaged (cut, chewed, etc.), an enzyme alliinase converts PRENCSO into 1-propenyl sulfenic acid. This compound is then converted into propanethial-S-oxide by an enzyme lachrymatory factor synthase (earlier this reaction was considered spontaneous). The reaction looks like this:

[image: pathway]

Propanethial-S-oxide is the major cause of the flavor and aroma of onion. However, it is a volatile compound i.e. vaporizes very quickly. When its vapors reach the eye, it causes tears because of being a lachrymator (*aka* tear gas) i.e. as soon as it comes in contact with cornea, it triggers a nervous response which leads to activation of lachrymal (tear) glands.

*PS:* when propanethial-S-oxide comes in contact with cornea, a small amount of it reacts with water to form sulfuric acid. This sulfuric acid is the cause of itching and irritation in eyes due to onion. Also, scientists are now trying to genetically either modify or stop the production of lachrymatory factor synthase enzyme to produce tearless onions. This (modification) has even been achieved to a high efficiency, as another answer discusses. However, making tearless onions could prove harmful to the crop in several ways, as discussed [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/296796112_Tearless_Onion).

***EDIT:*** As asked in comments, I will add some details about how the sulfuric acid is produced from the reaction between propanethial-S-oxide and water.

The only resource I could find giving some details about this was [Marta Corzo-Martínez, 2014](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/269332973_An_overview_of_bioactivity_of_onion). They summarize the complete pathway in the following diagram:

[image: diagram]

After applying some common chemistry principles, the concerned reaction turns out to be:

$\ce{4~C_3H_6SO~+~4~H_2O \rightarrow 4~C_3H_6O~+~H_2SO_4~+~3~H_2S}$

As you see, one of the products of hydrolysis of propanethial-S-oxide is hydrogen sulfide ($\ce{H_2S}$). Just like $\ce{H_2SO_4}$, $\ce{H_2S}$ also causes irritation in the eyes (its effect on eyes has been well documented, see [Lambert *et al*, 2006](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0048969706001240) as an example). Thus, the produced $\ce{H_2S}$ only increases the irritation and itching in the eyes caused due to $\ce{H_2SO_4}$.

***BONUS:*** Another interesting point here is runny nose. propanethial-S-oxide is actually the compound responsible for the smell and flavor of onions. But, it causes tears by exciting the lachrymal glands i.e. reflexive lachrymation. propanethial-S-oxide excites the trigeminal nerve (the fifth cranial nerve) causing activation of lachrymal glands. Interestingly, the nerve endings of trigeminal nerve are also present in the nose, along with the eyes. So, this compound can also activate the lachrymal glands from your nose, and since the lachrymal duct is joined from eyes to nose, you can also experience runny nose along with tears and irritation in eyes.

**References:**

- [Propanethial-S-oxide | University of Bristol](http://www.chm.bris.ac.uk/motm/pso/psojm.htm)
- [Alliin | Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliin)
- [Tear Gas | Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tear_gas)
- [Timothy William Lambert, Verona Marie Goodwin, Dennis Stefani, Lisa Strosher, Hydrogen sulfide ($\ce{H_2S}$) and sour gas effects on the eye. A historical perspective, *Science of The Total Environment,* Volume 367, Issue 1, 15 August 2006, Pages 1-22, ISSN 0048-9697, https://doi.org/10.1016/j.scitotenv.2006.01.034](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0048969706001240)
- [Encyclopedia of Perception, Volume 1 - 
  E. Bruce Goldstein,
  SAGE, 2010](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=6M3NSNm6MlkC)
- [The Neurology of Lacrimation – How an Ear Infection Can Cause Dry Eye - 
  by Noelle La Croix, DVM, Dip. ACVO](http://www.vmcli.com/veterinary-articles-neurology-of-lacrimation.html)

Comment: I'm curious about the sulfuric acid. The oxidation number of S is rather low in propanethial S-oxide, are you certain that sulfuric and not sulfurous acid is produced? I know about the relatively low stability of the latter.

Answer (score 22):

This is due to a lachrymatory agent called as syn-propanethial-S-oxide.

The process goes as follows:

- Lachrymatory-factor synthase is released into the air when we cut an onion.
- The synthase enzyme converts the amino acids sulfoxides of the onion into sulfenic acid.
- The unstable sulfenic acid rearranges itself into syn-ropanethial-S-oxide.
- Syn-propanethial-S-oxide gets into the air and comes in contact with our eyes. The gas diffuses through the air and, on contact with the eye, it stimulates sensory neurons creating a stinging, painful sensation.
- The lachrymal glands become irritated and produces the tears.

  Tears are released from the tear glands to dilute and flush out the irritant. In this case it is to reduce the effects of sulfuric acid,a chemical that could damage the eye if it was not for the tear reflex that renders the sulphuric acid largely harmless.

So, we can stop tear production by not irritating our eyes by using the onions which produce less irritants.

> Through a single genetic transformation in onion (Allium cepa), a crop recalcitrant to genetic transformation, we suppressed the lachrymatory factor synthase gene using RNA interference silencing in six plants. This reduced lachrymatory synthase activity by up to 1,544-fold, so that when wounded the onions produced significantly reduced levels of tear-inducing lachrymatory factor.

---

Sources: https://www.loc.gov/rr/scitech/mysteries/onion.html

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18583530

Comment: Interesting. I was wondering, though, if it has to come in contact specifically with the eyes? As it seems for myself that the smell alone (well, the irritating gas actually) starts the tears, and the painful feeling comes from my sinuses rather than the eyes? I also noticed I sustain the feeling much longer if I pinch my nose. Yet that might be confirmation bias ^^

Comment: @spectras I believe so; I have a pair of goggles that I wear when cutting onions and it seems to prevent the effect.

Comment: Just because it's a random thing I learned working in fast-food for 3 months at the ripe age of 16 before being fired, soaking onions in ice water dramatically reduces irritation. Maybe the ice isn't needed, can't recall.

Comment: @ChrisSchneider As temperature decreases enzyme activity and diffusion decreases.

Comment: @chrisschneider also the propanethial-S-oxide and sulfuric acid are water soluble, so it prevents their vaoprization

Comment: @spectras In my experience, your observation is not confirmation bias, it's simply true. Whatever causes the tears, it makes its way through the nose. Pinch your nose for good (f.ex. with a clothespin and from the start to the end of the process) and there will be almost no tears at all. I got this tip from someone who cooks all the time, I tried and it just works.